# how to submit a form without input submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I would like to submit a form without a input submit.

I want to submit this form after click on an `img` tag .

I have a form like this:

```
 <form name="form-form"  action="http://localhost/php/enteqal-ax.php" method="post" id="submit_form ">
     <input type="hidden" id="value1" name="value_php">
 </form>
```

I have an image like this:

```
 <img id="img" width="100px" height="100px" src="http://www.shadyab.com/assests/images/upload/thumb_open-menu-roko-restaurant_(17)3.jpg">
```

my java script code :

```
     $('#img').click(function() {
   var img_src = $('#img').attr('src');

   $('#value1').val(img_src);
   $('#submit_form').submit(); // not works at all


});
```

Comment: id="submit_form " remove space from last and again try with the same js code

Comment: You have a space after the name `id="submit_form "` remove that space and it will be like this `id="submit_form"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please remove the space present at the end of your form id like:

```
id="submit_form "
```

change it to

```
id="submit_form"
```